# ASP.NET MVC Saving a view as HTML file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a pretty basic page that has a few images via relative paths that I need to save to a .html file.

I have used this in the past but had problems with the images.

```
public static class ActionResultExtensions
{
    public static string Capture(this ActionResult result, ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        using (var capture = new ResponseCapture(controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response))
        {
            result.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
            return capture.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public class ResponseCapture : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpResponseBase _response;
    private readonly TextWriter _originalWriter;
    private StringWriter _localWriter;

    public ResponseCapture(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        _response = response;
        _originalWriter = response.Output;
        _localWriter = new StringWriter();
        response.Output = _localWriter;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        _localWriter.Flush();
        return _localWriter.ToString();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_localWriter == null) return;

        _localWriter.Dispose();
        _localWriter = null;
        _response.Output = _originalWriter;
    }
}
```

I'd like to know how to get the result WITH all of the CSS and images downloaded along with the HTML in a nice little package.

Comment: Sorry somehow this got submitted without my finishing

Comment: I updated the bottom of my question

Comment: Can you show an example of what the page you are trying to save looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If you need it all in an HTML file you will need to do a tonne of nasties to inject css, js and images into the actual document, however you could use something like an MHT file which is a bundle of all resources required for a page.

this does the MHT thing by the looks, probably other options out there as well.
http://www.aspnetmht.com/Examples.aspx